# Calculate the slope based on two columns "coordinates"

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have pandas dataframe that looks similar to this (date is index):

```
>>>            J01B_X   J01B_y   J02C_x   J02C_y...
date
2019-06-23     0.45    1.12       4.56    1.1
2019-06-24     0.22    1.18       5.5     0.8
2019-06-25     0.35    1.10       6.1     8.3
...
```

- The original table has 58 columns like this , basically each observation has 2 values , the x and the y value.

I want to calculate the slope based on the X and Y values  that are in the columns:
(0.45 1.12, 0.22 1,18, 0.35 1.10) -> slope for observation J01B based on J01B_X and J01B_y
(4.51 1.1 , 5.5 0.8 , 6.1  8.3) -> calc slope for observation J02C based on  J02C_X and J02C_y

the thing is that I have 58 columns like this to calculate their slope based on two columns each time.

In the end I would like to have one row,not  in the same original table,  with the calculation of the slope based on the two columns, something like this (this is fake numbes):

```
>>>            J01B   J02C    ....   
               0.13    0.05
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example creates a pandas Series which is basically a single dimensional pandas object like a row.  You can create a dataframe from that if you wish

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

slopeB = stats.linregress(df['J01B_X'], df['J01B_y'] )
slopeB = slopeB[0]

slopeC = stats.linregress(df['J02C_x'], df['J02C_y'] )
slopeC = slopeC[0]

#Create Pandas series with slope data
slopes = pd.Series([slopeB, slopeC], index = ['J01B', 'J02C'], name="Slope")
slopedf = pd.DataFrame(slopes).T
```

slopes looks like this:

```
J01B   -0.278195
J02C    4.233791
Name: Slope, dtype: float64
```

slopedf looks like this and is a DataFrame with one row:

```
           J01B      J02C
Slope -0.278195  4.233791
```

Both slopes and slopedf can be queries the same way, but the series will return the numerical value of the entry and the slopedf will return a single element series with the data.  Even though the Series appears as a column when printed I think this is what you want.

```
#output of slopes['J01B']
-0.2781954887218037

#output of slopedf['J01B']
Slope   -0.278195
Name: J01B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I updated the answer to go with your updated question.